# how to redirect from plugin to a template file in the same plugin

Tags: wordpress, redirect, plugins

I am using [wpjobboard Plugin](https://demo.wpjobboard.net/job/front-end-web-developer/) I want the users to redirect to the payment page when they submit the Apply Online form,

I have created a template file in wpjobboard/templates/job-board/order-payment.php

currently the page is redirected to same page using this code

wp_redirect(wpjb_link_to("job", $job)."#wpjb-sent");

instead of redirection to the same page I want it to redirect to order-payment.php file.

Thanks.